# Disabling empathy balloon

Tags: ubuntu, notifications, empathy

How can I disable empathy's balloon that shows up when someone sends me a message?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this forum: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1311812

> In your Contact List, go to `Edit`-> `Options`. Open the Notifications tab. Deselect `Enable bubble notifications` and `enable notifications when the chat is not focused`.

Comment: Please don't leave just a link, if the linked site becomes unavailable, the answer is of little use.

Comment: @Sathya - *'if the linked site becomes unavailable'* I doubt it but if you insist. Where in the SU documentation/FAQ does it say this?

Comment: There have been enough discussions on this on Meta http://meta.superuser.com/questions/500/is-downvoting-link-only-answers-acceptable http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1/best-way-to-handle-answers-with-just-links-in-them http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1393/is-it-ok-to-downvote-link-only-or-link-copy-paste-answers @richbax

Comment: @Sathya - Thanks for taking the time to provide this information. +1

Comment: You're welcome. FYI the downvote isn't from me. @ricbax